# In ubuntu, where should I place these files?

Tags: ubuntu, path, sfml, undefined-reference

I am having some problems in ubuntu 12.04.

I have SFML library that I want to use in my code::blocks project.

In the SFML folder there are two sub-folders - **include** and **lib**. 
include contains header files (.h files).
lib contains library files (.so files).

I am unable to directly link the library with my project because compiler cannot find the files.

I researched in google and found out that I have to place the sfml files in standard path to link them in code blocks properly.
So what is this default standard location where I am supposed to put these files ?

Edit : After doing a lot of googling, I come to know how to put the headers and modules in the correct standard locations. But after compiling and running (either from codeblocks or from the terminal), these undefined reference errors are coming :-

```
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_action@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_next@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_unref@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_name@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_unref@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_unref@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_new@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_receive_device@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined reference to `std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...)@GLIBCXX_3.4.20'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_devnode@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_enable_receiving@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_new@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_get_fd@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_unref@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_property_value@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_filter_add_match_subsystem_devtype@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_get_list_entry@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_scan_devices@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_add_match_subsystem@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_syspath@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_new_from_netlink@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_new_from_syspath@LIBUDEV_183'
/usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.so: undefined reference to `udev_device_get_parent_with_subsystem_devtype@LIBUDEV_183'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the content of the **include** folder in **/usr/include** or **/usr/local/include** and the content of the **lib** folder in **/usr/lib** or **/usr/local/lib**

You can also specify the include and libraries paths when you compile your code. For example, if you are using `gcc` you can do this:

`gcc prog.c -oprog -I/path/to/include/folder -L/path/to/libraries/folder -lLibraryName.so`

Comment: **/usr/include** &  **/usr/local/include**  both are there.  Can I put them in any one of these ?

Comment: @Raj yes, it depends on the compiler, most of them will look in both of those locations.

Comment: okey so I copied the include to /usr/include and lib to /usr/lib, but still codeblocks is giving many **undefined reference** errors. Do I need to do something in codeblocks ?

Comment: @Raj If the header files are inside a folder, you may have to change the `#include` statements in your code eg: if the headers are in the`/usr/include/newHeaders` folder, use `#include "newHeaders/header.h"`.

Comment: I checked. The include folder contains another folder called SFML, which contains header files. So, after I did this in my main.cpp file in codeblocks : **#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>** and it says : **fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory**

Comment: okey I did that, but i am still getting the same error.  **fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory**

Comment: @Raj here is a forum post that explains how to add new include and libraries paths to Code Blocks http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=9366.0

Comment: I already know how to add include and libraries paths to Code::Blocks, but for some reasons undefined reference errors are coming up.

Comment: @Raj it seems that you are missing some dependencies, here is a list of all SFML's dependencies, make sure you've got them all. http://www.sfml-dev.org/faq.php#grl-dependencies

Comment: I installed each of them manually. Still I am getting the same undefined reference errors.

Comment: Are you linking those libraries when you compile your code ? the error messages says that the compiler can't find some stdc++ and udev methods. Also, make sure all the libraries are for the same architecture (32-bit or 64-bit) and you have the versions required.

Comment: I installed all the dependencies that are required for sfml. I found out what dependencies I need in the sfml wiki : https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Installing-SFML-dependencies .

Comment: Why do I need to link sfml libraries ? I copied them in the standard locaton (usr/local/include/   and   usr/local/lib)

Comment: Unlike headers files which you reference in your code with `#include` statement the compiler doesn't know which libraries your code uses, that is why you need to specify them when you compile your code, since you've placed them in `/usr/local/lib` you won't have to specify were the compiler should look for them.